# xamarin studio has a debug host option in settings in release build?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Since I started building using the new Xamarin Studio, it has added (over and over and over again - once for each install!) an option in the Settings for my app called "Debug Settings" And "Enabled" is ON, and "Xamarin Studio Host" is set to Automatic...  (Is this why debugging doen't work on my device anymore?)

My question is.. I just built with the RELEASE / AppStore build, and I know for SURE that the RELEASE build has this turned on..  WHY?

I'm hoping that it didn't end up in my App Store Binary that I sent to Apple yesterday.. I don't want this junk in the final version...

How do I disable this being created, and what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Xamarin Studio does not add the debug options in the Settings bundle for Release, Ad-Hoc, or App Store builds. It will only add those options if you've enabled debugging for those build configurations in the Project Options.

As far as adding the options over and over again, that bug has been fixed in newer releases of Xamarin Studio.

Comment: If true, it isn't doing it, except, it is.. I uninstalled and reinstalled and it is back.  Perhaps, it is because I have multiple projects and one of them is still in debug mode?  - Does it not change it for everything when you change the upper drop down?

Comment: Just double checked the options for all the libraries used, as far as I can tell they are all release too...

Comment: Ok, I just saw that I had "Emit Debugging information" added in the configuration - which might be OK as it would give me useful stack traces (I wrote a routine to upload stack/exception info on exceptions), but how to turn off this menu option?

Comment: I removed the Emit Debugging, and turned on optimization - in case I get a reject by the App Store...  (and ready for next update...)